# Iterating through a dictionary for X number of times

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

Assume the dictionary contains more than 10 key-value pairs. The dictionary ought to be sorted by values (of integers). Print out the top 10 values (and corresponding keys). I think there is a better solution that what I have given here.

```
for keys in sorted(x):
   c=c+1
   if c>10:
      break
   else:
      print keys, x['keys']
```

Comment: There is no concept of "first" 10 dictionary entries in Python because dictionaries are unordered. Do you mean "any 10 entries"?

Comment: yes, any 10 entries is fine.

Comment: Sorry, Correction. I will need to sort it by values in descending order (integer values). Print the top ten values.

Comment: You probably want to edit your question to reflect this correction.

Comment: Thanks for t reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for key in sorted(x, key=x.get, reverse=True)[:10]:
    print key, x[key]
```

For really large `dict` you should consider using a heapq

```
from heapq import nlargest
for key in nlargest(10, x, key=x.get):
    print key, x[key]
```

Comment: gnibbler sir, what is the difference between your solution and this- topten = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)[:10]

Comment: That yields the key/value pairs as you iterate over it. Mine just yields the keys. You could try them both and see which is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

There is no order defined on dictionary keys, so the "first" keys are not well defined. Specifically, what you did is easier done with `x.keys()[:10]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
topten = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x:-x[1])[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `dict` for X number of times using the following code.

**Python 3.8**

```
def highest_contributor(self, top=1):
    slice_dict_only_to_keys = list(self.contributors.keys())[:top]
    for _key in slice_dict_only_to_keys:
        self.log("Top Contributor: {} ({})".format(_key, self.contributors[_key]))
```

Don't worry about integers and incrementing them with your code. You don't need them.

Simple, readable and Maintainable.